# Using PrintWriter in Java

Tags: java, printwriter

I trying to run multiple command shells from Java. I am able to do that (and get the output in the console using PrintWriter). However, I want to be able to get the output of each command in a separate String. Is that possible?

Here is a part of the code :

```
 File wd = new File("/bin");
    Process proc = null;
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream())), true);
    out.println("cd ..");

    out.println("ls");
    System.out.println("moving to /var directory");
    out.println("cd /var/");
    out.println("ls");
    //get output of ls command in string variable
    out.println("cd ..");
    out.println("cd /etc/");
    out.println("ls -a");
    out.println("ps");

    out.println("exit");
    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        proc.waitFor();
        in.close();
        out.close();
        proc.destroy();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you can do the `ls` in Java (File.listFiles()) and just call out to the OS for the `ps` (or get some Java library to do even that, too)?

Comment: Thanks for response, but putting the ouput of each command in a file will not be usefull (write in file and then parse it)...I still looking for for somehow to convert PrintWriter to String...it will resolve it...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting a section like

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append(line).append("\n");
}
String commandOutput = builder.toString();
```

after each command?  Is that roughly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for response, it was really interresting but what I am trying to do is to get for each comamnd output is string , The commandOutput string gets all commands result in one String ...:-)

Comment: **@Jeff Johnston: Could be a printerWriter declared of Array output? in that case we could separate each command in separte string with the builder instance **